# Может ли @PostConstruct работать по разному на Mac OS и Windows Server 2012

Tags: java, spring, windows-server-2012

Есть класс который подтягивает конфигурации из `.properties` файла в методе `initPaths()` отмеченным `@PostConstruct`. Разработка ведется под `Mac OS` и тут все работает стабильно. Но когда я начал разворачивать приложение на `Windows Server 2012` получилось что в стучае с `Windiws` метод `initPaths()` вообще не вызывается.

```
@Value("${traned.data}")
private String tranedData;

@PostConstruct
void initPaths() {
    log.debug("Init Path Call");

    isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().indexOf("win") > 0;
    root = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();

    ...дальше просто преобразования со строками...
}
```

Как это происходит: беру один и тот же `jar` архив запускаю на Mac все работает и в лог записывается `Init Path Call`, а на Windows в логе запись отсуствует ну и программа падает без этих данных.

Comment: Java-программа запускается не в какой-либо операционной системе, а в JVM. JVM во всех операционных системах одинаковая и строго следует спецификации. Думаю, вы сами пытаетесь вылезти за пределы JVM и этим рушите программу. Например, зачем вычисляются переменные `isWindows` и `root`?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev это переключатель OS чтобы запускать на моей локальной машине и на сервере код с разными путями к нужным файлам. А может быть дело в том что у меня на Windows стоит Java(TM) SE Runtime Enviroment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)?

Comment: Такой переключатель не нужен. От особенностей среды надо максимально абстрагироваться.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev да я понимаю но как это сделать не знаю, к тому же это первый тестовый стенд... Я потом это переделаю нормально у меня проблема с `@PostConstruct` почему java 9.0.1+11 его не подхватывает(((

Comment: `@PostConstruct` может не вызываться только в одном случае - если бин не инстанцировался. А такое, если исключить ленивую инициализацию, может быть только в том случае - программа упала раньше.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev да я тоже так думал... но очень странно удалил 9 поставил 8-ю java и завелось 0_о